# Local networking: File sharing permissions over AFP

Tags: finder, network, file-sharing, afp

I am having trouble getting read/write file sharing working over my local network.

I have shared a folder via AFP, named 'Pictures', with a specific user through System Preferences > Sharing.

By doing this I have successfully made it to the point where I can view the Pictures folder from another computer on the network.

However, when I attempted to move a picture from one folder to another on the remote computer, I got a message from Finder saying, "Finder wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this."

I have used the "Get info" panel on the source computer to recursively set permissions to "Read/Write" for all files and directories under the "Pictures" folder.

As a test, I went in to the Terminal and navigated to /Volumes/Pictures. I attempted to run a command similar to "mv /Volumes/Pictures/Folder1/Picture1.jpg /Volumes/Pictures/Folder2/" and I got a message saying "Permission denied".

However, to my confusion I could successfully run the commands "touch /Volumes/Pictures/Folder1/test" and "touch /Volumes/Pictures/Folder2/test".

All files and folders within the Pictures folder are writable and readable by the owner, within the POSIX permissions on the source computer.

Anybody have any ideas as to what could be going on here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you connect to the AFP share, are you connected as a user or a guest?

Comment: I am connecting as a user that I have set up in System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing as being able to Read / Write. I have entered in a password on the other computer which is now saved for subsequent connections.

Comment: Maybe try adding 'Everyone' = Read & Write to the files you are trying to access on the host computer (and apply to all subfolders)